# How to write equations in Overleaf?

Tags: equations

[image]

I want to write this equation in my paper. Kindly help me with this.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem you're facing? Do you know how to write equations in LaTeX in general, but have problems with these particular equations? Or are you looking for a tutorial on LaTeX math mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing equations is a matter of LaTeX. For example, your second equation can be written as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\left\{\begin{aligned}
 SOC & = \frac{Q(t)}{Q_\mathrm{Max} }\cdot 100\\
Q(t) & = Q(0) - \int_0^t \eta_b I_b\, dt
\end{aligned}\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

I write above document example (MWE: Minimal working Example) in WinEdt editor and compile with MIKTeX. You can write as shown and then compile in Overleaf. Result will be the same.

Comment: @Teepeemm, you are right. Corrected now.

Comment: Notice also that Zarko's output is better than the original image.